# How can I make a navbar at the bottom of a webpage using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a navigation bar at the bottom of my webpage using CSS, but cannot figure out how to make it stay at the bottom.

HTML:

```
<div id="navbar" style="position: ??????; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; height: 50px; background-color: #333; padding: 0; font-weight: bold; color: #c5cad0;">

</div>
```

When I set position as 'absolute', the bar stayed in the middle of the page when I scrolled down.

When I set position as 'fixed', the bar showed up on the bottom of the screen before I scrolled down.

When I used 'static, relative, or sticky', the bar was below the content, but not full width and not all the way at the bottom.

I am trying to get the bar at the bottom of the page, below all of the content (like Stack Overflow does).

Comment: Could you please try moving your navbar within the footer?

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Without having some idea of the structure of your HTML any answer will be just a guess.

Comment: I'm sorry but how isn't this an MRE? It shows what I have but nothing else. What is above the page is insignificant in this case as long as it is enough to have a need to scroll down.

Comment: @amcilwain25 your question isn't clear you are mentioning at the bottom of the page and then mentioning its not working when scrolling what behaviour are you expecting if you could specify that would be helpful. Also any screenshot of it will be helpful too

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;  /*Navbar will not move from its position if you want when you scroll it stuck at top then just replace position: fixed with sticky*/
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #11101b;
  color: #fefefe;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.left-navbar,
.hamburger {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.heading {
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 20px;
}

ul:nth-child(5) {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.searchBox {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-left: 10vw;
}

.searchBox input[type="text"] {
  width: 70%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.searchBox input[type="submit"] {
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.hamburger {
  display: none;
}

.hamburger-icon {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

.change .bar1 {
  transform: translate(0, 8px) rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 8px) rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, 8px) rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 8px) rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: translate(0, 8px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
  transform: translate(0, -11px) rotate(45deg);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1340px) {
  .searchBox {
    margin-left: 5vw;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1160px) {
  .searchBox {
    margin-left: 4vw;
  }
  .left-navbar {
    width: 90%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1060px) {
  .searchBox {
    margin-left: 2vw;
  }
  .searchBox input[type="submit"] {
    min-width: 60px;
  }

  li,
  li:hover {
    padding: 13px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .left-navbar {
    display: none;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  .hamburger {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: end;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }

  .hamburger-icon {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .left-navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 300px;
    width: 100vw;
  }

  .left-navbar.active {
    display: flex;
  }

  .left-navbar li {
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: #11101b;
    color: #fefefe;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .left-navbar ul {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .searchBox {
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Navbar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div class="navbar">
        <h2 class="heading">Navbar</h2>
        <div class="hamburger">
          <div class="hamburger-icon" onclick="toggleNavbar(this)">
            <div class="bar1"></div>
            <div class="bar2"></div>
            <div class="bar3"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="left-navbar">
          <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Services</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Contact us</li>
            <li>
            <div class="searchBox">
                <input type="text" name="search" id="search-input" />
                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <script>
      let isHamburgerClicked = false;
      function toggleNavbar(x) {
        x.classList.toggle("change");
        document.querySelector('.left-navbar').classList.toggle('active');
        isHamburgerClicked = !isHamburgerClicked;
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```